# Equivalent of incrementing a C/C++ pointer in Java?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, pointers, programming-languages

I do have somewhat of a feeling that people will try to beat me over the head and say "You're not supposed to do that!" (and I'm quite aware of this fact); nevertheless, here's my problem:

Suppose you've got the following C++ code:

**EDIT:**
I think I haven't shown enough of what I'm trying to do, even though most of the answers were excellent. So here's an edited version of my code. The heart of it is that a every iteration I still need to use an *array* of vales that happens to be a sub-array of `x`, not just a single value at an index:

```
unsigned int n = 2000; // or any other number for that matter
double * x = new double[n];
double resultArray;

// fill array with meaningful data
// do all kinds of initializations

for( int i=0 ; i<someNumber ; ++i ){ //someNumber ~ 1900

    // do some stuff

    for (j=0 ; j<someSmallerNumber ; ++j){ //someSmallerNumber ~ 15
        resultArray[j] = x[j] * someFunction(resultArray[j]);
    }

    ++x; //increment pointer to the first element of the array

    // do some more stuff

}
```

**EDIT:** The reason I use `++x` in the outer loop is that if I used `x[outerIndex+innerIndex]` instead of just `x[innerIndex]` I would perform *many* more additions per iteration and this is an algorithm heavy on algebra, so I'm trying to squeeze some performance out of it.

I would like to point out that my algorithm never tries to read non-existent memory. This is simply a speed of processing issue where I'm trying not to recalculate current array index more times than I have to. This runs perfectly well, and I'm happy with it.

Now I'm trying to implement a similar algorithm in Java (and Java in not quite my area of expertise). I do know, however, that Java does not really give you access to pointers and handles everything as an Object. My question is, of course, is there an *efficient* way to perform an equivalent of `++x` where `x` is an address of the first element of an array in Java? Is there perhaps a way to remove the first element of an array instead? Are there good fast algorithms to look at if it's not a part of built-in Java array manipulations?

Thanks in advance! = )

Comment: You are probably better off replacing `double * x = new double[n];` with `std::vector<double> x(n);` because this frees you from having to `delete[] x;` manually.

Comment: I also believe that the C++ version is prematurely optimized. Any decent optimizer will see that part of the index calculation can be moved out of an inner loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is not C++.  The things you do in C++ to gain speed do not necessarily apply to Java.  This is one of those cases.

Using the for(int val : x) in Java will not, as some people suggest, give you any advantage over:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    int val = x[i];
}
```

Reference here; http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2

What people are saying here about the VM is free to make optimizations at runtime is correct.

So, yes, you do need to be beat over the head a little :-). While Java and C++ look similar, what you do in one is not what you would do in the other in all cases: to write good Java, you must think in terms of Java; for C++, you must think in terms of C++.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `for-each` loop:  `for (double d : theArray)` - it is the idiomatic way to do it and it gives the VM the clearest optimization opportunities.

If your condition for breaking depends on the current position in the array, you are probably best to use a classic `for` loop with a hand-written counter - sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The efficient way is to use an index, and increment it in the loop.

The JIT is entitled to hoist bounds-checks outside the loop, if it can prove to its own satisfaction that the index variable does just cover the range in an orderly fashion. In your case it may be difficult for the JIT to prove that `someSmallerNumber` is always small enough, but it could still hoist outside the inner loop. once it has checked `someSmallerNumber` once per outer loop.

For the simplest case, with a so-called "for-each", even if the compiler emits bytecode that uses an index internally (I don't know whether it does or not), then the JIT should immediately see that the index cannot ever be out of bounds.

> if I used x[outerIndex+innerIndex]
>   instead of just x[innerIndex] I would
>   perform many more additions per
>   iteration

There is no guarantee that the JIT is dumber than you are - it can hold the values of repeatedly-used partial calculations in registers if it wants to. I'm afraid I don't know whether, in practice, a JIT will spot that `x[outerIndex+innerIndex]` can be computed differently by re-using an address in the middle of the array. The re-used value isn't a GC-able pointer, adds complication, blah blah, so it may or may not be capable of the exact same optimization you made in C++. But a good C++ optimizer is probably capable of making the optimization without your help, so I wouldn't be at all surprised if a JIT can too.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: There's no direct equivalent.

Use indices or use `for (double d : array_of_double)` - the `for` construct is easier for the VM to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

An idiom I have seen employed quite often is to read the value from the array and store it in a local variable, manipulate that local variable, and finally store the result back:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someNumber; ++i)
{
    double val = x[i];

    // do heavy lifting with val

    x[i] = val;
}
```

Of course, if you only *read* from the array, you don't need to write the value back. In that case, just use the for-each loop:

```
for (double val : x)
{
    // ...
}
```